# Outlook 2016 on Exchange server is not processing rules

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office, exchange-2016

- Someone has asked me to help with his exchange server in the office,
  however I am a network administrator and not really experienced with
  Windows and Exchange.
- Problem here is that they have a set of rules to organize incoming
  emails. The exchange server is pulling the emails from the original
  email-Server and all workstations are configured to communicate with
  the Exchange server only.
- What I already tried is delete all rules and set them up again on the
  server. Tried to make sure that the names of the rules are not too
  long because I read about a size limit that these rules have. Looked
  on the workstations that they don't have additional rules.
- After creating all the rules, it worked for a few days and then the
  rules stopped being processed again.
- In the screenshot an example of a rule: "After receiving of the
  message and the message is received from address do the following:
  Move to folder name The rule is turned: On"

[image: "After receiving of the message and the message is received from do the following: Move to folder The rule is turned: On"]

When I in Outlook on a workstation manually select to process all rules, all the related emails are moved accordingly.

Why are they not processed automatically? What can I do to further investigate the issue?

Comment: Does it only affect the particular user or all users in the environment are affected?

Does this issue can be reproduced in both Outlook client and OWA?

Where did you recreated the rules, within Outlook or OWA?

Comment: It is only one user on the exchange server. All workstations with outlook use this user to pull mails from the server, who itself pulls them from the internet. The old admin set this up to have the exchange server scan for malware ect. The rules were fist created in outlook on one (only this one) workstation. I deleted the rules there, made sure no other outlook instances have rules and recreated them in OWA on the server. This only helped for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only occurs to this specific user in Outlook client, it's suggested to try resetting the send/receive settings file (SRS file) which is by default located at "C:\Users%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook". You can rename the "**Outlook.srs**" file to "Outlook.srs.old", then restart Outlook and check the result.
[image]

If it can be reproduced in OWA as well, I'd suggest try clearing up all rules by pressing "Windows + R" and type "**outlook /cleanrules**", then recreate rules from OWA.
[image]

In case the issue remains, I'd also recommend running the command below to check if the mailbox is set as the journalingReportNdrTo mailbox, this could cause the issue that inbox rules cannot run automatically.

```
Get-TransportConfig | fl JournalingReportNdrTo*
```

More details, see [Transport and mailbox rules in Exchange Online or on-premises Exchange Server don't work as expected](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/transport-and-mailbox-rules-in-exchange-online-or-on-premises-exchange-server-don-t-work-as-expected-8729e935-4b04-f849-5998-0a5074d594e8).